# Python - Why wont unicode just die?

Tags: python, unicode

I am being forced to use python 2.7 and have recently had a resurgence of unicode errors which seem to be indestructible. I thought I had solved the problem for good by creating the following method which worked for several months without problems but recently all sorts of unicode errors have been popping  up:

```
def kill_unicode(s):
    if not isinstance(s, (int, np.integer)) and not isinstance(s, (float, np.float)):
        s = s.encode('unicode_escape', errors='replace').decode('utf-8')
    return(s)
```

However, when I apply that to the recent new data, I keep getting the standard unicode error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 542: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Note this is not limited to 0xc3. Any ideas on how to improve the above function to be more universal? Note ignoring the value and removing the char from the string entirely is not a viable option, though replacing it with the unicode \x03 syntax is.

Update:

Your suggestion still does not work. The below still provides ASCII errors.

```
def kill_unicode(s):
    if isinstance(s, str) or isinstance(s, bytes):
        s = s.encode('unicode_escape', errors='replace').decode('utf-8')
    return(s)
```

Comment: `if not isinstance(s, (int, np.integer)) and not isinstance(s, (float, np.float)):` lol what? There's an infinitude of other possible classes this could be, why only protect against these 4? And why put them in two separate `isinstance` calls?

Comment: [enjoy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgHbC6udIqc)

Answer (score 3):

It is ASCII that should die, not Unicode.

The problem is that you are not checking that `s` is actually a Unicode instance to start with - if it is a bytestring, in 2.7 when you call `encode` on it, it attempts to decode first, using the ASCII encoding.

You should only do any of this if `isinstance(s, str)` is true. If you make that check, then your existing checks that s is not an int or a float - which, as FHTMichell points out, is a strange selection - become unnecessary.

Comment: I believe you mean `isinstance(s, bytes)` or `isinstance(s, str)`.  There is no `bytestring` class.

Comment: Yes you're right, corrected.

Comment: This does not seem to resolve the issue. I receive the same issue regardless of the initial test. An early version of the above function used to test for string, but was removed because it prohibited some other issue previously and checking for just floats/ints was a better solution.